# Git interactive rebase not applying previous commits

Tags: git, rebase

I'm trying to reorder commits in my development branch using git's interactive rebase. This is the list of commits I have in my branch:

```
git rebase -i HEAD~6

pick e7c0cd9 Create VERSION file and set to 1.0.0
pick 26700a6 Modify shortcode for columns
pick dfa535a Increase greybox h3 bottom margin to 30px
pick 47f11bc Increase margin and padding for greybox-item
pick 98c2e3a Create style for lt-greybox
pick d4840be Create style for .image class to provide spacing
```

So what I've done is to move e7c0cd9 to the bottom of the list, thus making it the most recent commit:

```
pick 26700a6 Modify shortcode for columns
pick dfa535a Increase greybox h3 bottom margin to 30px
pick 47f11bc Increase margin and padding for greybox-item
pick 98c2e3a Create style for lt-greybox
pick d4840be Create style for .image class to provide spacing
pick e7c0cd9 Create VERSION file and set to 1.0.0
```

The rebase happens without any merge conficts as the progress indicator cycles through the commits it's rebasing, but when it completes it doesn't apply any of the previous commits, it only applies e7c0cd9 and not the 5 before it.

Would there be any reason why this would happen - I have searched Google, but can't find any logical explanation?

**Output of git reflog after rebase:**

Output of git reflog (I hope this outputs the formatting correctly):

```
e7c0cd9 HEAD@{0}: rebase -i (pick): updating HEAD  
1d225f9 HEAD@{1}: rebase -i (pick): Create style for .image class to provide spacing  
52e9fc0 HEAD@{2}: rebase -i (pick): Create style for lt-greybox  
5febbc8 HEAD@{3}: rebase -i (pick): Increase margin and padding for greybox-item  
61709a0 HEAD@{4}: rebase -i (pick): Increase greybox h3 bottom margin to 30px  
b87b0b3 HEAD@{5}: rebase -i (pick): Modify shortcode for columns  
8e325f3 HEAD@{6}: rebase -i (start): checkout HEAD~6
```

**Using Git v2.0.1 on Mac OSX 10.10.2**

Comment: Can you run `git reflog` after you have completed your rebase and show the result?

Comment: what does you see if you run the command tig?

Comment: @elhadi, `tig` isn't built into Git. There is no reason to assume that another user has it installed. It might be better to suggest `gitk`, which ships with Git.

Comment: @GoonyanHarir, it is very hard to read this kind of output in comments. Please edit your question (link at the bottom-left of the question) and copy your `reflog` output there instead.

Comment: All your commits seem to have been picked correctly. What is the reason you claim that they haven't been applied?

Comment: @aronisstav After performing a `git log -10` after the rebase, it doesn't show the other five commits. Also those five missing commits aren't reflected on the front end...

Comment: I have performed a `git reset --hard` on commit before the rebase to revert my code back to how it was and performed another `git rebase -i HEAD~6` and it happens again.

Perhaps I should just create a new branch off of my development branch and `git cherry-pick` the commits in the order I want them.

Very confused.

Comment: Hmmm... On a second look, there is no `rebase -i (finish)` message, which in a rebase of mine looks like: `7feb234 HEAD@{0}: rebase -i (finish): returning to refs/heads/...`. Not sure how to move on from here...

Comment: What's the output of `git status`?

Comment: @Chris `On branch develop
nothing to commit, working directory clean`